# custom layout in navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I am new to android,  I follow this tutorial to create Navigation Drawer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

I make the navigation drawer successfully but I dont know how to change framelayout to my custom layout with button, textview....My app just show menu and blank framelayout, how can I solve this ?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="asdsadsad" />

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="@color/purple_dark"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
       android:dividerHeight="0.1dp" 
       android:listSelector="@drawable/ic_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Listen this xml is for DrawerLayout. So do you want to add the Buttons and etc in your DrawerLayout ? If yes then create a separate row.xml file and then infate that xml and create a custom adapter also.After that you can get the buttons or textviews, whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a RelativeLayout on LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout and you can build your whole layout inside that

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add another layout you need to gie it to your `closeDrawer`and `drawerOpen`.

Please refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690659/cannot-customize-navigation-drawer/33733005?noredirect=1#comment55234865_33733005)